Submenu list menu with three levels
I have a menu that is made up from nested lists on three levels. The elements in the second level are open only when an element is clicked (This is what I want), but the elements on the third level is already opened.
This is my html code:
<nav id="menu">
<header class="major">
<h2>Menu</h2>
</header>
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="introduzione.html">Introduzione</a></li>
    <li>
        <span class="opener">Arcani maggiori</span>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="arcani-maggiori-il-matto.html">Il Matto</a></li>
        <li><a href="arcani-maggiori-il-mago.html">Il Mago</a></li>
        <li><a href="arcani-maggiori-la-papessa.html">La Papessa</a></li>
        <li><a href="arcani-maggiori-limperatrice.html">L'imperatrice</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <span class="opener">Arcani minori</span>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="opener">Le Spade</span>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="arcani-minori-le-spade.html">Asso di Spade</a></li>
            <li><a href="arcani-minori-le-spade.html">Due di Spade</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>   
    <li><a href="strumenti.html">Strumenti</a></li> 
</ul>
</nav>                                               
                                    

This the code in the css file:
/* Menu */
#menu ul {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #3d4449;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.075em;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase; }
  #menu ul a, #menu ul span {
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 0.625em 0; }
    #menu ul a:hover, #menu ul span:hover {
      color: #f56a6a; }
    #menu ul a.opener, #menu ul span.opener {
      -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      text-decoration: none;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      position: relative; }
      #menu ul a.opener:before, #menu ul span.opener:before {
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        display: inline-block;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-rendering: auto;
        line-height: 1;
        text-transform: none !important;
        font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
        font-weight: 900; }
      #menu ul a.opener:before, #menu ul span.opener:before {
        -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, -ms-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
        color: #9fa3a6;
        content: '\f078';
        position: absolute;
        right: 0; }
      #menu ul a.opener:hover:before, #menu ul span.opener:hover:before {
        color: #f56a6a; }
      #menu ul a.opener.active + ul, #menu ul span.opener.active + ul {
        display: block; }
      #menu ul a.opener.active:before, #menu ul span.opener.active:before {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        transform: rotate(-180deg); }

#menu > ul > li {
  border-top: solid 1px rgba(210, 215, 217, 0.75);
  margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0 0; }
  #menu > ul > li > ul{
    color: #9fa3a6;
    display: none;
    margin: 0.5em 0 1.5em 0;
    padding-left: 1em; }
    #menu > ul > li > ul a, #menu > ul > li > ul span {
      font-size: 0.8em; }
    #menu > ul > li > ul > li {
      margin: 0.125em 0 0 0;
      padding: 0.125em 0 0 0; }
  #menu > ul > li:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0; }


I'd like to do this how the second level. Excuse me for my English, my native language is Italian.
